# Rails Heroku Migration Stuck

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

After a push to heroku around 30 minutes ago, we are seemingly not able to do anything in the rails console or  perform a migration.

I'm able to do a `heroku run rake db:migrate`

And it appears to start:

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
Running rake db:migrate on app... up, run.8092
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (1.4ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
Migrating to AddQuestionsCountToCampaigns (20160215204320)
   (0.9ms)  BEGIN
== 20160215204320 AddQuestionsCountToCampaigns: migrating =====================
-- add_column(:campaigns, :questions_count, :integer)
```

But then it just hangs there and never actually completes.

Likewise I can connect to the rails c, but I can't do anything like `Campaign.new` or `Campaign.last`. It just hangs there:

```
Loading production environment (Rails 4.2.0)
irb(main):001:0> Campaign.new
```

And never actually does anything.

Any ideas what might be going on? Staging works fine. The logs also seem to be working and I don't see any crashes. I've also tried a `heroku restart` and that didn't seem to help.

Adding Migration:

```
class AddQuestionsCountToCampaigns < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :campaigns, :questions_count, :integer
    add_index :campaigns, :questions_count
  end
end
```

Comment: Do you have many campaigns? What is `Campaign.count`? Are you using PostgreSQL? What is the migration you are running (is there anything else except of adding column)?

Comment: Added migration. Yes - just the standard Heroku Postgres. Campaign.count actually failed - said there were too many connections. I went ahead and did a pg:killall and now things seem to be working?

Comment: ~23k campaigns though, so not a ton

Comment: Have you tried running migrations after `pg:killall`? Also you can try running them with `--verbose` flag

Comment: Yea, they worked after `pg:killall`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For future reference:

Trouble was with too many pg connections opened (running in rails console `Campaign.count failed: said there were too many connections).

Solution was to run `pg:killall` and rerun migrations